# Partial revokes with MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I want to use MySQL [partial revokes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/partial-revokes.html) in MariaDB, but there does not seem to be any reference of it in the docs, so is there are workaround?

I grant user `foo` privileges on `*.*`, and I want to partially revoke its permission to select column `password` on table `users` - how can I do this?

```sql
CREATE USER 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%';
REVOKE SELECT (password) ON production.users FROM 'foo'@'%';
```

Such thing results in:

```sql
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'foo' on host '%' on table 'user'
```

Version: `10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log`

Perhaps I could do something like this easily with roles? If so, can you give examples to do so?

Answer (score 1):

[MDEV-14443 negative grants](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14443) is actively being worked on so hopefully 10.9.

At the moment creating the grants excluding your password is one option.

The other is putting the password (by which I hope you mean a uniquely salted hash or KDF) in a different table.